# Tcl lreplace can't replace braces?

Tags: syntax, tcl, substitution, braces

What should do this code sample?

```
set l { A B C D }
lreplace $l 1 2 \[ \]
```

It returns `{A {[} \] D}`, however I want to have `{A [ ] D}`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code does exactly what you want it to, you're just reading the string rep of your output and misunderstanding it:

```
% set l { A B C D }
 A B C D 
% foreach elem $l { puts $elem }
A
B
C
D
% set j [lreplace $l 1 2 \[ \]]
A {[} \] D
% foreach elem $j { puts $elem }
A
[
]
D
% join $j
A [ ] D
```

When you read the string rep, you're seeing it escape the [ and ]. As you can see from the foreach output, the actual values are what you're asking for. You can use `join` to get the string you're interested in if what you want is just a string with the characters in question.